# why my modal is not showing even though its direct copy from bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am currently learning with OMDB API and using bootstrap and JQuery. So what's wrong with my code is when i clicked the 'See Detail', it's supposed to show modal that i'm gonna use to show the movie detail from API, but the modal is not showing. Here is the code :

(You can basically ignore other than the modal one (maybe), but in case you wanna try it, i included it because from youtube tutorial it was working fine, but mine not)
HTML :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WPU MOVIE</a>
    <button
      class="navbar-toggler"
      type="button"
      data-bs-toggle="collapse"
      data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
      aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Search Movie</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt-3 justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <h1 class="text-center">Search Movie</h1>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Movie's title..."
          id="search-input"
        />
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-dark" type="button" id="search-button">
            Search
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div class="row" id="movie-list"></div>
</div>


<!-- so i remove the button and took just the data-toggle and data-target in my JQuery -->
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
function searchMovie() {
    $('#movie-list').html('');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.omdbapi.com',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { //data yang akan dikirimkan ke url seperti parameter
            'apikey': 'd250323f',
            's': $('#search-input').val()
        },
        success: function(result) {
            if (result.Response == 'True') {
                let movies = result.Search;
                $.each(movies, function(index, data) {
                    $('#movie-list').append(`
                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="${data.Poster}">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">${data.Title}</h5>
                                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">${data.Year}</h6>
                                <a href=# class="card-link see-detail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-id="${data.imdbID}">See Detail</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    `); //The 'See Detail' to work with the modal is in the <a> tag just above this comment
                });
                $('#search-input').val('');
            } else {
                $('#movie-list').html(`<h1 class="text-center">${result.Error}</h1>`);
            }
        }
    });
}
$('#search-button').on('click', function() {
    searchMovie();
});
$('#search-input').on('keyup', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        searchMovie();
    }
});
//... another chuck of code 
});
```

Comment: Have you included the bootstrap library in the page? What errors are displayed in the console?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes, i have included it in my code, i just not included it here. unfortunately, there wasn't any error in console whatsoever, but because you mentioned it, so i made one. i made test() function that contains console.log('test'); and add onclick="test()" in <a> property and has "(index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick ((index):1)" in my console. any solution?

Comment: `onclick="test()"` and `test is not defined` usually means your `function test() { }` definition is not globally scoped, probably defined inside doc.ready

Comment: @freedomn-m oh you're right, it's because of scope., the `test()` is working now, but my modal still not

Comment: When I run the code you have include here and add bootstrap js and css to the code then everything works just fine.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen yeah, that's actually the problem. the video which i learnt works just fine, and i literally have no clue what's wrong lol